How to access keyboard Layout on macOS Xcode C++
I worked on a C++ project (Ubuntu) reading keyboard layouts using GTK/GDK/X11´s functions( like gdk_keymap_get_entries_for_keycode() or gdk_keymap_translate_keyboard_state() )
I develop in VSCode and build with meson.
Now I want to adapt the same program to run on macOS Sonoma 14.4 and Xcode 15.3.
Unfortunately I have never worked on the mac so I am a complete beginner. Therefore I would appreciate if someone could give me a hint:

Is it possible to use GTK/GDK/X11 on macOS?

Is using GTK/GDK/X11 a recommended path that I could follow ? Or should I use something instead of GTK/GDK/X11? If so what?

Is com.apple.hitoolbox.plist the right place to get the currently used keyboard
layout?

How would I access this keyboard layout file? ( Are there equivalent functions to dk_keymap_get_entries_for_keycode() or gdk_keymap_translate_keyboard_state() )

How can I build the project? in Xcode? Do I use meson? Something else?
(On  the GTK-website they proposed to use jhbuild.  Would I use jhbuild instead of meson or together with meson or not at all?)
Thank you very much!!



The first hit from my internet search engine turned up: https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/macos
